# Return data having value 0

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm a newbie so may be a simple SQL query for you guys.

In a table I have records having `PFAULT` `0` and `1` against one `SRID`. I want to get only those records which have `0` as `PFault`. If any record has `PFault` `1` than I don't need that record.

E.g. a record can have both values i.e. `0` and `1` but I need only those records which don't have `1`. field type is `bit`.

sample table data

```
ID   | SRID  | PFault 
---- | ----  | ----
2255 | 1212  | 0
2256 | 1212  | 0
2257 | 1212  | 1
2258 | 1213  | 0
2259 | 1213  | 1
2260 | 1214  | 0
2261 | 1214  | 0
2262 | 1216  | 0
```

as per above I need data for

```
SRID 1214 and 1216
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost phrased it in English already in a way that can be translated quite straightforwardly to SQL. That's a very good start. That straightforward translation then looks like:

```
select srid from table
except
select srid from table where pfault = 1;
```

Comment: SQL, The Original Fluent API :)  (and I say that only half jokingly - in many cases, it's very true: if you can spell it out in English, there's a pretty close translation to SQL)

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are referring to the SRIDs.  If that is all you need:

```
select srid
from t
group by srid
having max(Pfault) = 0;
```

You can also write this as:

```
have max(cast(Pfault as int)) = 0
```

If you want the original rows:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.srid = t.srid and t2.Pfault = 1);
```

Comment: thanks for answer, yes I need SRIDs, but I cannot use MAX function as field type is 'bit' for pfault.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SRID
```

FROM #Table Otr
WHERE PFault = 0 AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #Table inr WHERE inr.pfault = 1 AND inr.SRID = Otr.SRID)
GROUP BY SRID